# Efficient way to find the greatest result of A mod M in a range of numbers

Tags: java

I am writing a code that takes two numbers N and M and finds the greatest result of A mod M for all the numbers of A in the range 1,2,3,...,N-1,N.

1 ≤ N,M ≤ 10^9

My code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    long n=readLong(), m=readLong(), a=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        a=Math.max(i%m, a);
    }
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

My code works for small ranges like in the test case below:

Input`

```
10 5
```

Output

```
4
```

However, it is still not efficient enough (TLE). Is there any way to make looping through all the numbers faster?

Comment: Isn't that just `min(N, M-1)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to loop. Lets look at what \$0 \le i \le 10\$ and \$i\ \%\ 5\$ results in.

$$
\begin{array}{l|l l l l l}
i & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
i\ \%\ 5 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0\\
\end{array}
$$

From here we can see that if \$n \ge m\$ the answer is \$m - 1\$. If this is not the case then the answer is \$n\$.